# React App Showing Blank Page When Redirecting To Sign-In Page

Tags: reactjs

React app shows blank page when redirecting to sign-in page. I am wondering if it has something to do with AuthCheck being depracated? It works well on other pages, but blanks out when I click on Sign-in button. Here is an example of my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { useAuth,  AuthCheck } from 'reactfire';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { Input } from '../SharedComponents/Input';
import { Container, Button, makeStyles, Typography, Snackbar,  } from '@material-ui/core';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import MuiAlert, { AlertProps } from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import { Navbar } from '../Navbar'

const Alert = (props:AlertProps) => {
    return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant='filled' {...props} />;
}


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    googleButton:{
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(66,133,244)',
        marginTop: '2em',
        padding: '0',
        color: 'white',
        height: '50px',
        width: '240px',
        border: 'none',
        textAlign: 'center',
        boxShadow: 'rgb(0 0 0 / 25%) 0px 2px 4px 0px',
        fontSize: '16px',
        lineHeight: '48px',
        display: 'block',
        borderRadius: '1px',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto, arial, sans-serif',
        cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    googleLogo:{
        width: '48px',
        height: '48px',
        display: 'block'
    },
    typographyStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto, arial, sans-serif;',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: '2em'
    },
    containerStyle: {
        marginTop: '2em'
    },
    snackBar: {
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: '#4caf50'
    }

});

interface SignInProps{
    history: RouteComponentProps["history"];
    location: RouteComponentProps['location'];
    match: RouteComponentProps['match'];
  }

  export const SignIn = withRouter( (props:SignInProps) => {

    const auth = useAuth();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { history } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleSnackOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true)
    };

    const handleSnackClose = (event?: React.SyntheticEvent, reason?:string) => {
        if(reason === 'clickaway'){
            return;
        }

        setOpen(false);
        history.push('/')
    }

    const sign_in = async () => {
        const response = await auth.signInWithPopup( new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
        if(response.user){
            handleSnackOpen();
        }
    };

    const sign_out = async () => {
        await auth.signOut();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Container maxWidth = 'sm' className={classes.containerStyle}>
                <Typography className={classes.typographyStyle}>Sign In Below</Typography>
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <Input name="email" placeholder="Place Email Here" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <Input name="password" placeholder="Place Password Here" />
                    </div>
                    <Button type="submit" variant='contained' color='primary'>Submit</Button>
                </form>

                <AuthCheck fallback={
                    <Button className={classes.googleButton} onClick={sign_in}>Sign In With Google</Button>
                }>
                    <Button variant='contained' color='secondary' onClick={sign_out}>Sign Out</Button>
                </AuthCheck>
                <Snackbar message={'Success'} open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleSnackClose}>
                    <Alert onClose={handleSnackClose} severity="success">
                        Successful Sign In - Redirect in 6 seconds
                    </Alert>
                </Snackbar>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
});
```

Also, I would like to know if there might be a better way to do this?

'''

```
The above error occurred in one of your React components:

at http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1514:71
at C (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:123659:37)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:123402:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:123604:29)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:123033:30)
at BrowserRouter 
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:122654:35)
at Provider 
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:120713:20)
at FirebaseAppProvider 
(http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:130056:30)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error 
handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more 
about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1437
```

'''

'''

```
Uncaught Error: A React component suspended while rendering, but 
no fallback UI was specified.

Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to 
provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.
at throwException (react-dom.development.js:20220:1)
at handleError (react-dom.development.js:22400:1)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22520:1)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22134:1)
at react-dom.development.js:11380:1
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11326:1)
at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11375:1)
at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11363:1)
at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22262:1)
at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3730:1)
at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5912:1)
```

'''

Comment: Check on your developer console for any error thrown in execution

Comment: I have updated the post,  what should I do with the error?

Comment: There is an error above the first error msg you pasted as per the message